# Can Excel VSTO add-ins call Excel web add-ins?

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

Can Excel VSTO add-ins call Excel web add-ins (and the opposite) ?
Can Excel VBA custom functions call Excel web add-ins (and the opposite) ?

Answer (score 2):

Excel VSTO add-ins can not call to Excel web add-ins. However, there is a way to run the Excel COM add-ins in a compatible mode on Windows, while running the web add-ins in other platforms (Mac and Online). Please check out this document: [Make your Office Add-in compatible with an existing COM add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/make-office-add-in-compatible-with-existing-com-add-in). For custom functions, similar mode also works for functions defined in XLL, please check out this document: [Extend custom functions with XLL user-defined functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/make-custom-functions-compatible-with-xll-udf)